# How i can force the unique Cell to stay and not disappear when I click any cells in my table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The main goal to let player A pick vertical and player B to pick horizontal.

**Please run the snippet code to understand my question better!, thanks a lot**

I have unique cell with Symbol S and color red, however if i click any cell, it disappears and normal numbers replace it. How i can force the unique Cell to stay and not disappear when I click any cells in my table?

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function prs(c, r) {
  showTable(c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }

  return ret;
}

function showTable(chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      str += "<td onclick='prs(" + col + "," + row + ")'";
      if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        str += " class='grn' ";
      }
      str += ">";
      str += board[row][col];
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);

var getUnique = function(){
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  tdElements[
    RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length)
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell');
  // update the text of the cell using the class
  document.querySelector('.uniqueCell').textContent = 'S';
};
getUnique();
```

```css
td{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
td:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
.grn{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: tomato;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Comment: hi mikoto does my answer is what you want or need modification   ,  if so accept or tell me to modify

Comment: hi, i figured it out sometime before i saw your answer, my apologizes, i'm stuck here, if you could help, would appericate and accept, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394748/how-to-force-unique-cell-to-delete-other-cells-upon-clicking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added

`document.querySelectorAll("#ff td")[uniqueCell].innerHTML='S';`

`document.querySelectorAll("#ff td")[uniqueCell].className ='uniqueCell';`

`uniqueCell` is the random td number

```js
var isCol = 0;
var board = [];
for (r = 0; r < 7; r++) {
  var line = [];
  for (c = 0; c < 7; c++) {
    line.push(RandomGenerator(50, 500));
  }
  board.push(line);
}

function prs(c, r) {
  showTable(c, r);
  isCol = (isCol + 1) % 2;
  document.querySelectorAll("#ff td")[uniqueCell].innerHTML='S';
  document.querySelectorAll("#ff td")[uniqueCell].className ='uniqueCell';
  
}

function toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var ret = false;
  switch (isCol) {
    case 0:
      if (row == chosen_row) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
    case 1:
      if (col == chosen_col) {
        ret = true;
      }
      break;
  }

  return ret;
}

function showTable(chosen_col, chosen_row) {
  var str = "";
  str += "<table border=1>";
  for (row = 0; row < 7; row++) {
    str += "<tr>";
    for (col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
      
      str += "<td onclick='prs(" + col + "," + row + ")'";
      if (toColor(col, row, chosen_col, chosen_row)) {
        str += " class='grn' ";
      }
      str += ">";
      str += board[row][col];
      str += "</td>";
    }
    str += "</tr>";
  }
  str += "</table>";

  document.getElementById("ff").innerHTML = str;
}

function RandomGenerator(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

showTable(-1);

var getUnique = function(){
  var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#ff td');
  uniqueCell=RandomGenerator(0, tdElements.length);
  tdElements[
    uniqueCell
  ].classList.add('uniqueCell');
  // update the text of the cell using the class
  document.querySelector('.uniqueCell').textContent = 'S';
};
var uniqueCell;
getUnique();
```

```css
td{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}
td:hover{background-color:lightgreen;}
.grn{
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
}

.uniqueCell {
  background-color: tomato;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ff"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `showTable(...)` generates table every time and replaces with `innerHtml` with new one. `getUnique` marks cell only at beginnning.

The possible solution, to store `var randomCell = RandomGenerator(...)` before `showTable(-1)`, and set class `uniqueCell` in `showTable(...)`